# Error: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble getting this code to work.  It is for a shopping cart page of my project that displays the total amount of the items selected, but the code for the math computation part it not working. The part that is not working is the decimal total part.

```
    public string Display()
    {
        decimal total = Product.Price * Quantity;
        string displayString = string.Format("{0} ({1} at {2} each = {3})",
            Product.MovieName,
            Quantity.ToString(),
            Product.Price.ToString(),
            total.ToString("c"));

        return displayString;
```

Comment: Please consider converting either Product.Price or Quantity to a numerical value from string. This is what the error message is trying to communicate to you.

Comment: it would be helpful if you also posted the `Product` definition and the `Quantity` declaration. But your error seems to say that either `Product.Price' or `Quantity` is a string

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour].

Comment: `Operand`: "An operand is the part of a computer instruction which specifies what data is to be manipulated or operated on". So in your calculation, you have two operands: `Product.Price` and `Quantity`. The error message shows that the compiler has analysed their types and found that one is a `string`, and the other is an `int`. Since there is no implicit (or explicit) conversion from string to number types, it's not possible to perform the calculation. See the question yours is a duplicate of for details on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What type this properties have: `Product.Price` & `Quantity`?
Before doing multiplication you should be sure that all operand are numeric.

Comment: This should be a comment.